# Make models and controllers for a mysql database in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-admin

I have a mysql database with some tables in it , is there anyway to create models and controllers for this database using larvael framework ? I mean the fast way to do it , any command ... 
Thank you for helping me , any suggestion will be hellpfull , thank you .

Comment: You can make models and controllers using `artisan` command. However, when you would want to migrate your code to production, you would need database migration files as well. So, for that, you will need `createIfNotExists()`(or similar method) instead of `create()` for your database migration.

Comment: You answers are here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a plugin (if you can call it like that) that provides such functionality.

The fastest way to achieve what you are looking for (without a plugin) would be to go at every table and create the model using `php artisan make:model <ModelName> -a`. This would create the model, the migrations, the controller and the factory.

Another alternative was to loop through all the tables and make make a script to run the command above related to the model/table

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague. Laravel ships with a tool called [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan), this is PHP cli tool to help with the development of your application. You can access this by running the following command

```
php artisan
```

[Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan) has a whole lot of stuff, that it can do and create.